# Flatten triple nested list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I want to use a triple list comprehension in python to to make a flat list.

```
mynested = [[['1229'], [['2020-11'], ['2020-1'], ['2020']]], [['1230'], [['2020-12'],['2020-2'], ['2020']]]]
```

I would like it to work like this.

```
short=[]
for a in mynested:
    for b in a:
        for c in b:
            short.append(''.join(c))
for shrt in short:
    print(shrt)
```

Outcome:

```
1229
2020-11
2020-1
2020
1230
2020-12
2020-2
2020
```

But how do I get this outcome with a list comprehension?

Comment: You cannot get "prints" from a list comprehension. Do you mean something else?

Comment: Nested list comprehensions are not all that mysterious. The loop structures appear in the same order  whether inline or not `[''.join(c) for a in mynested for b in a for c in b]` if you know the nested loop structure you know the list comprehension structure.

Comment: It's not as easy as you imply.  Some of your strings are nested 3 levels deep ('1220'), some are nested 4 levels deep ('2020-11').

Comment: List comprehensions are for *building* lists, not printing their contents.

Comment: You can definitely use `print` in a list comprehension **but you shouldn't**

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by getting an "output" of "prints", but doing what you want with a triple-nested list is very similar to a double-nested list.
So how about -

```
output = [''.join(x) for z in mynested for y in z for x in y]
```

You can now do -

```
for x in output:
    print(x)

# 1229
# 2020-11
# 2020-1
# 2020
# 1230
# 2020-12
# 2020-2
# 2020
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**
You could try this, it gives the desired output:

```
print(*[''.join(c) for a in mynested for b in a for c in b], sep='\n')
```

You cannot make a print function in a list comprehension because that will return None values. For instance this example:

```
numbers = [1,2,3]
[print(x) for x in numbers]
```

the output will be the numbers in the list and also a list of three `None` values.

Comment: Sure you can use `print` in a list comprehension, but you *shouldn't*. But you *can*

Comment: You can put it in a list comprehension but it will return a list of None values.